# How to show html / base64 in react-native?

Tags: html, react-native, webview, base64

I want to build 3d payment application with react-native by webview package. I want to use webview for 3d proccess. But my payment company return html content with encoded via base64.
Like this;

```js
threeDSHtmlContent : 'PGh0bWw+DQo8IS0tIHRyb3lTdGFydFN1Y2Nlc3MuaHRtIC0tPg0KPHRpdGxlPkdPPC90aXRsZT4NCgk8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJDb250ZW50LUxhbmd1YWdlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ciI+DQoJPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iUHJhZ21hIiBjb250ZW50PSJuby1jYWNoZSI+DQoJPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iRXhwaXJlcyIgY29udGVudD0ibm93Ij4NCgk8bWV0YSBodHRIgaWQ9ImJ0blNibXQiPjwvY2VudGVyPg0KCTwvbm9zY3JpcHQ+CQ0KCTwvZm9ybT4NCgk8L2JvZHk+DQo8L2h0bWw+DQo='
```

I can show this in html

```
<a href="data:text/html;base64,V2VsY29tZSB0byA8Yj5iYXNlNjQuZ3VydTwvYj4h"></a>
```

OR

```
<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,V2VsY29tZSB0byA8Yj5iYXNlNjQuZ3VydTwvYj4h">
  The “iframe” tag is not supported by your browser.
</iframe>
```

How about react-native? I tried this with WebView but it throws error and webviews coders say that "we cant support this." I lost its url but there was.

```js
  <WebView
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     source={{ source: `data:text/html;base64,${BasketStore.threeds.deneme}` }}
  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your WebView's source prop is correct? Can you try this instead?

```
<WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    source={{ html: `<a href="data:text/html;base64,${BasketStore.threeds.deneme}"></a>` }}
    />
```

or

```
<WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    source={{ html: `
        <iframe src="data:text/html;base64,${BasketStore.threeds.deneme}">
            The “iframe” tag is not supported by your browser.
        </iframe>
    ` }}
    />
```

Comment: adamım sen bu işleri biliyorsun.